# How to delete a node and its connected nodes with Neo4j cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

For example, I want to delete `Actor` node with id = "005A" and its connected `Movie` nodes. The relationship between Actor and Movie node is `ACTED_IN`.

I have tried this cypher query:

```
MATCH (a:Actor {id: "005A"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m)
DELETE a, r, m;
```

but it didn't work, I got `TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction` error.

Anyone can give a solution?

**UPDATE:**

I found out that there is relationship from other node (`Agency`) to `Actor` node which labeled as `OWNED`. So the diagram is like this:

```
(aa:Agency)-[o:OWNED]->(a:Actor)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDITED]

You cannot delete a node unless all of its relationships have also been deleted. In your case, it is possible that the `a` and/or `m` nodes have relationships other than `r`.

To get the set of relationship types associated with `a` and `m`, you can use the following (I've limited the result to 10 rows, in case `a` and/or `m` have a lot of relationships`):

```
MATCH (a:Actor {id: "005A"})
OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[rx]-(a)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m)
OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[ry]-()
RETURN a, r, m, COLLECT(DISTINCT TYPE(rx)), COLLECT(DISTINCT TYPE(ry))
LIMIT 10;
```

I suspect that your results will show types other than `ACTED_IN`.

The following query should delete the actor and all movies s/he acted in:

```
MATCH (a:Actor {id: "005A"})
OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[rx]-(a)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m)
OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[ry]-()
DELETE rx, ry, r, a, m;
```

Comment: I run `MATCH (m:Movie)-[r]->() return r;`, it returned empty row.

Comment: With your query, the `r` and `m` returned <null>, the next two collects  returned empty list (`[]`)

Comment: You said all of relationships must be deleted, what if the `Actor` node has **relationship from other node**? For example: `(aa:Agency)-[:OWNED]->(a:Actor)`. Should I delete the `OWNED` relationship too?

Comment: Yes. I have updated my query -- it should not return results for `COLLECT(DISTINCT TYPE(rx))` in that case.

Comment: Ok, it seems I was right. I need to delete the `OWNED` relationship too. I will edit my question to give chance to you all to answer my question :)

Comment: See my updated query. It should now return results for `COLLECT(DISTINCT TYPE(rx))` in that case. And I now also answer your question.

Comment: There is problem with your query, it only delete the `Actor` node and its relationship, but it doesn't delete the connected `Movie` nodes. Also, I have a question, what is the meaning of relationship line that doesn't have arrowhead like this: `(x)-[r]-()` ?

Comment: Have you actually tried my query? It should delete all movies the actor acted in. Arrowlessness means that the directionality does not matter.

Comment: When I write that line, I didn't see your answer is being edited. Ok, it works now. Great answer :)

Comment: I have one more question, is the order of variables in `DELETE rx, ry, r, a, m` important or have influence in the query? like I should put the relationship variables first before nodes?

Comment: The order does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the id is encoded as a string property ? I guess the id of the movie database is an integer and thus the id should not be encapsulated in quotes :

```
MATCH (a:Actor {id: 5})
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m)
DELETE a, r, m;
```

Comment: nope, it's really string and the value is unique. To prevent anyone think like this in future, I will change the example a bit.